# How do I commit the changes on a working copy to a different (but identical) repository?

Tags: svn, repository, backup

This seems to happen to me all the time lately. I have a repository "X". That repository has a backup. One day the server hosting repository X dies, so I have to create a new location for my SVN repository using the backup. Here is the problem:

I have hours of work done on my working copy. When I click commit, it tries to commit the changes to the dead repository URL. I want the working copy to start treating the NEW repository X without any hassle, but running "switch" doesn't work ("These are not the same repositories").

What I usually do is create a patch from the working copy, check out the new repository and apply the patch. Recently however, I keep getting errors and crap from the patch files, so I no longer trust them. The latest solution for me has been to create a whole new repository and copying the files over, losing all the file history.

Obviously this is unacceptable, **so if anyone knows a way to start working with a new repository smoothly and effortlessly, please reply.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [`svn switch --relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)? That allows you to update the repository's root URL, rather than just the path within the repository.

Comment: The answer just had to be embarrassingly simple... :-)